# Cannot use PowerMockRunner because of AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner not found error

Tags: java, spring, mockito, powermock

I am writing a unit test for a class and using

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class).
```

I get incompatible types error saying

> "Found org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner but required org.junit.runner.Runner."

Gradle dependencies:

```
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.1.0'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock:1.6.1'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-core:1.6.1'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2'
```

Comment: For the record: are you sure you need PowerMock? It only *legit* reason to use it: when you test 3rd party code and you have to mock new/static calls there. When you write your own production code, then **good** designs are testable with Mockito alone (and please note that PowerMock forces you to use Mockito that are years old - you miss all the good stuff in the newest version of Mockito 2)!

Comment: I want to check if the code is executing try-catch blocks under different scenarios. All the catch blocks have LOGGER statements, LoggerFactory is used as static object in my class. Hence, opting PowerMock to check if logging statements were executed.

Answer (score 0):

You should add to your `build.gradle`

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.6'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.6'
```

Versions here are important because PowerMock doesn't support mockito 2+ until 1.7.0

Comment: I tried this combination and still running into error

Comment: this clearly indicates dependency issue. Check if you have incorrent dependency in your classpath. Run `gradle clean build --refresh-dependencies` and if it doesn't help try `gradle dependencies` to analyze dependencies. Check the following snippet which worked for me: https://gist.github.com/opensso/c34cb1d56d85fbaf6c0f3220c85070f7

Comment: i had other mockito  dependencies which were conflicting, this combination works.